# Extremely slow custom function in pandas aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

I have to calculate the coefficient of variation (std/ mean) in a moving window in a dataset I have. The code is pretty simple:

```
start_time = time.time()

channel_data = data[data['channel_id'] == ch].sort_values('datetime')
channel_data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(channel_data['datetime'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.floor('d')
channel_data = channel_data.set_index('datetime')

rolling_data = channel_data.rolling('{}D'.format(window)).agg({ 'val': coeff_of_var })

rolling_data = rolling_data.groupby(rolling_data.index.floor('d')).last()[window:]

print('Time needed: {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

My problem is that it's extremely slow.

`coeff_of_var` can either be a custom function of `scipy.stats.variation` or a lambda function - I tried them all. The custom function I use is

```
def coeff_of_var(series):
    return series.std() / series.mean()
```

`data` is a DataFrame with dimensions [3070584 rows x 5 columns]. `channel_data` contains ~457710 rows.

This code is inside a cycle and it takes so long that I had to stop it before the `print` of the first execution time...

Instead of calculating the coefficient of variation, I tried calculating separately both std and mean, which is, to substitute the function in the curly brackets of line 5 with: ['std', 'mean']. The new line is:

```
std_rolling_data = channel_data.rolling('{}D'.format(window)).agg({ 'val': ['std', 'mean'] })
```

The execution time drops to:

```
Time needed: 0.9421329498291016 seconds
Time needed: 0.9423763751983643 seconds
Time needed: 0.9420042037963867 seconds
Time needed: 0.9560058116912842 seconds
Time needed: 0.9728689193725586 seconds
```

I also tried simplifying the custom function to:

```
def coeff_of_var(series):
    return 1
```

In this case the execution time is:

```
Time needed: 32.465901136398315 seconds
Time needed: 34.14194059371948 seconds
Time needed: 38.883220195770264 seconds
Time needed: 44.430686950683594 seconds
Time needed: 42.99840021133423 seconds
```

Do you have any ideas what's the cause of the slowness with the custom function?

---

## EDIT

You can replicate the problem with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import time

def coeff_of_var(series):
    return 1 #series.std() / series.mean()

nrows = 3070584
ntrue = 450000
window = 5

rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-01 00:00:00', periods=nrows, freq='min')
data = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': rng, 'B' : np.random.randn(len(rng)), 'C' : np.random.randn(len(rng)), 'D' : np.random.randn(len(rng)), 'E' : np.zeros(len(rng), dtype=bool)})

data.loc[np.random.choice(np.arange(nrows), ntrue, replace=False), 'E'] = True

start_time = time.time()

channel_data = data[data['E'] == True].sort_values('A')
channel_data['A'] = pd.to_datetime(channel_data['A'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.floor('d')
channel_data = channel_data.set_index('A')

rolling_data = channel_data.rolling('{}D'.format(window)).agg({ 'B': coeff_of_var })

rolling_data = rolling_data.groupby(rolling_data.index.floor('d')).last()[window:]

print('Time needed: {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your code with similar results, so I googled around a bit. What I found is unfortunately very vague, but I thought sharing it might still give you some ideas:

[Optimize Custom Grouping Function](https://medium.com/dunder-data/pandas-challenge-001-optimize-custom-grouping-function-44a9f2f321f8)

**TL;DR:**

> Pandas cannot optimize custom functions. It has a limited number of builtin grouping methods. All of these are optimized and should yield better performance.

While I know this is not a satisfying answer, I hope it will still be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the excessive slowness of your function is that you are using .agg instead of .apply. For custom functions you want to use .apply. Simply changing your code to:

```
rolling_data = channel_data.rolling('{}D'.format(window))['B'].apply(coeff_of_var)
```

and if you just make coeff_of_var return 1 your time will be:

```
Time needed: 0.80185866355896 seconds
```

If you change your code to calculate your coefficient of variation using your custom function or lambda x, the time it took for me was 10 seconds.

The fastest way would be as you noted:

```
rolling_data = channel_data.rolling('{}D'.format(window)).agg({'B':['mean','std']})
rolling_data = rolling_data['B']['std']/rolling_data['B']['mean']
```

Which for me took:

```
Time needed: 0.7320513725280762 seconds
```